# how to properly do formatfloat int64 for billion number

Tags: delphi-7

So, I am using delphi 7 and I have an edit box to put a number inside. since it'll be using it as a currency value, to make it easier for user, I add a thousand seperator for the number. I code this **onkeyup** event. Here's the code :

```
var 
  a, after : string; 
  iValue, iCode : integer;
begin
  a := edit1.Text;
  after := stringreplace(a,'.','', [rfreplaceall, rfignorecase]);
  val(after, iValue, iCode);
  if iCode = 0 then
  begin
    a := FormatFloat('#,##0',strtoint64(after));
    edit1.Text := a;
    edit1.selStart := Length(Edit1.Text);
  end;
end;
```

This works alright but whenever I put more than a billion, it didn't work.
For example I put 2.680.000.000, it'll show :

> 268.000.0000

How to fix this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't work because you are parsing the text into an `Integer` which has a max value of `2,147,483,647`. And why are you stripping off the decimal? "*it'll be using it as a currency*" - then why are you using `Integer`/`Int64` at all, instead of using `Currency`? And you shouldn't be manipulating the `TEdit` text inside the `OnKeyUp` event. If you want the text input to appear in a particular format, consider using `TMaskEdit` instead.

Comment: because our currency doesn't work like yours, perhaps. we didn't use any number after , . thanks for the idea.

Comment: `Currency` is a binary type, it doesn't know anything about `,.` and it is specifically designed for monetary values (hence its name). Look at `StrToCurr()` and `CurrToStr()`, and the global `CurrencyDecimals`, `CurrencyFormat`, `CurrencyString`, and `DecimalSeparator` formatting variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TMaskEdit with the following mask `###,###,###,###,###.00;` for example :

[image]